# Apache NIFI - 1.7.1 Build from source

Tags: maven, apache-nifi

I am trying to build Apache Nifi -1.7.1 from source, and chose the github tag `rel/nifi-1.7.1` to do so.

I am getting build failures on the `nifi-hive-processors` bundle with various cannot find symbols such as below.

```
[ERROR]error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Path
[ERROR] location: class ConvertAvroToORC
```

Any ideas on which branch/tag is safe to build from source?

Comment: Why not opening the issue right on Github? Perhaps the developers could help you better.

Comment: I have sent comms on their mailing lists. I don't think they have a public issues page, do they?

Comment: Clicking through their project page, I found "Issues" under the "Development" menu, Here't the direct link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/issues

Comment: `NIFI-6084` created. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved on the mailing list. Turned out to be a build error that resulted from the organization's local Maven repository. [source](http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/Build-Failures-on-compile-from-source-rel-nifi-1-7-1-td7095.html)